# showing a cell in gridview as hyperlink

Tags: c#, gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridview that is getting the data from a dataset which reads a XML file.
one of the fields in the xml stores a link to a website.

I want the gridview cell to show the link as a link in the html

How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific please, like are you talking about windows forms gridview or asp.net gridview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the column in the gridview to be a HyperlinkField

```
<asp:GridView id="myGrid" runat="server"
   <columns>
       <asp:HyperLinkField>
```